# Arch time zone: Wrong time due to local-time hardware clock

Tags: arch-linux, time

My hardware clock is set to local time (GMT +2) and my fresh Arch installation apparently thinks that it is not, so it adds 3 hours to it. I've fiddled with `hwclock` and `timedatectl` without hope. I'm hesitant to touch time settings in BIOS. How can I fix this?

Below is the output from `timedatectl`:

```
      Local time: Sun 2013-06-23 06:44:12 EEST
  Universal time: Sun 2013-06-23 03:44:12 UTC
        Timezone: Europe/Istanbul (EEST, +0300)
     NTP enabled: n/a
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: yes
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2013-03-31 02:59:59 EET
                  Sun 2013-03-31 04:00:00 EEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2013-10-27 03:59:59 EEST
                  Sun 2013-10-27 03:00:00 EET

Warning: The RTC is configured to maintain time in the local time zone. This
         mode is not fully supported and will create various problems with time
         zone changes and daylight saving adjustments. If at all possible use
         RTC in UTC, by calling 'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the documentation on the Arch wiki?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time

> The hardware clock can be queried and set with the timedatectl command. To change the hardware clock time standard to localtime use:
>
> `# timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`

Comment: Yes I have, and I did try it again now, no effect.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `timedatectl` before and after `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`?

Comment: `RTC in local TZ: yes` after that command; was `no` before. I recall doing this and rebooting a couple of times today.

Comment: I'm more interested in the Local / Universal / RTC times. It might also be worth checking `hwclock -r --localtime` to verify that your hardware clock hasn't been reset to UTC. I'm also assuming that your timezone has been set correctly in the new installation.

Comment: `hwclock` prints `Sun 23 Jun 2013 06:42:41 AM EEST  -0.812942 seconds` which is ahead by 3 hours. I'll update my question with output of `timedatectl`.

Comment: That all looks correct. Just to clarify, do you realize `set-local-rtc` won't change the time? `set-local-rtc 1` followed by `set-time` and a reboot should be the correct steps.

Comment: Also, remember that while localtime isn't going anywhere anytime soon, it isn't supported. At least according to the wiki, IIRC.

Comment: @strugee ; does this imply that I should change BIOS time instead?

Answer (score 0):

With my notebook optimus build

commands:

```
# hwclock --localtime (is returning the reverse)
# hwclock --utc
```

With ( `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`) is like localtime set to London time
and if I setup (`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`) show up current info.

Here in Recife-PE (America)

```
hwclock --localtime (returns right hardware clock, as i defined in bios)
and     --utc       (returns +3 hours from greenwich [London])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget `adjtimexconfig`, that does a good job comparing/updating system time from the hardware_clock (CMOS) info.

Just run `adjtimexconfig`.